# Execute a function at the end of the last effect of a Jquery.queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use fx and functions
I have a animation, and i would like to, at the end of the queue, do an ajax call.  
  I can't seem to make it work...  
  I have absolutely no idea how to procede...

that would a very very  rough example, but

```
$('#dvHeader').queue(function() {
  $('#dvLeftContent').slideDown(2000);
  $('#dvRightContent').animate({ backgroundColor: '#c71717' }, 2500)
  callAjax();
}
```

This code calls the callAjax function way before the last effect starts, in fact, almost as the first one is called.

  *The real case is a little more complex, i cannot use a callback of the animate effect, per example. I would like to know when the queue ends the last effect, or something like it.*
  How could I make that call to be triggered at the end of the last animation?

Comment: @NoProblemBabe, I dont' understand why you cannot use the callback of the animate function. The animation queue is unique to each element. If `animate` is the last part of the queue, its callback would fire after *all* the queue elements have finished. Please explain so I can understand how to help you.

Comment: I use those effects in a different way, more adapted to my small framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more careful look on how those Queues work, i found that if I just know the last element that will have it animated, i can queue my ajax call to it, it will place my function after the animation, something like:

```
$('#dvHeader').queue(function() {
  $('#dvLeftContent').slideDown(2000);
  $('#dvRightContent').animate({ backgroundColor: '#c71717' }, 2500);     
}

$('#dvRightContent').queue(function() {
  callAjax();
});
```

Of course, having the very same behavior that the callback.
Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

Try to set the callback method of the last effect (animate(), in your case) to your ajax function:

animate( params, [duration], [easing], [**callback**] )

Comment: As I've said before, I wanted to know how to apply a function at the end of the animation of the last element. The regular callback and chain are not what i am looking for. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Chain your animations along with your call together using the callback mechanisms:

```
$('#dvHeader').queue(function() { 
  $('#dvLeftContent').slideDown(2000, function() {
      $('#dvRightContent').animate({ backgroundColor: '#c71717' }, 2500, function() { 
          callAjax();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: As I've said before, I wanted to know how to apply a function at the end of the animation of the last element. The regular callback and chain are not what i am looking for. Thanks anyway